# Is there a way to 'switch OR engage/disengage' power between two different rotating shafts depending on a set RPM (wind speed)?

Tags: aerospace-engineering, aerodynamics, turbines, wind-power, shafts

I'm a final year mechanical eng student, I'm working on designing a prototype of a '**Hybrid vertical axis wind turbine (VAWT)**". This **hybrid** turbine consists of two types of VAWTs **Savonius** & **Darrieus**, one providing good 'starting torque' at 'low wind speed' another, needs 'high starting torque' and ' high wind speeds' but, can spin faster than **Savonius turbine** (no limiting drag). So I want to combine both of these to enjoy both of these turbines' advantages, thus trying to nullify each others' disadvantages. To do this I'll be needing a **switching OR engage/disengage** mechanism which can switch between both turbines' shafts... **Savonius turbine shaft** engaged with **Darrieus's shaft** until Savonius **assists** Darrieus in **starting & speeding up** and after **reaching its drag-limiting speed**, Savonius's shaft has to **disengage from the Darrieus's** thereby letting it **spin independently** with Savonius's shaft disengaged. Here the engaging & disengaging are going to happen at a **wind speed of 7 m/s**. Please suggest to me if there's a mechanism that can do this switching AND if there's a mechanism that **doesn't use electrical power or servo motors** for the switching actuation mechanism. Any suggestion is appreciated. Thanks in advance! :)
[image: Diagram of Savonius-Darrieus turbine, notice above's Savonius & below's Darrieus]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for a one-way clutch or freewheel. You will be familiar with these from a bicycle wheel chain-drive cassette. The chain drives the wheel until the wheel's rotational speed exceeds that of the driving sprocket.

Comment: Hi Transistor, thanks so much for the suggestion. IG so far from what I've researched, one-way clutches will be the best choice for the mechanism I want to achieve. I'll be researching more about it, and reverting back to you if I get stuck somewhere. If you're fine with it. If I can DM you?

Comment: All communications need to be done through the site. That way everyone benefits (if anyone benefits!). SE sites don't have a direct messaging system anyway. Meanwhile, do a search for "sprag clutch".

Comment: Oh alright! Sure everyone will benefit... at least I am! Haha
I'll read more on the sprag clutch. Thanks!